# Using icon tag and reusing them via css

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Bootstrap 5 (with the alpha release) has introduced their own Icon-Set. For example for edit icon it has svg tag like below:

```
<svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-pencil-square" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456l-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
</svg>
```

For the project I am working upon, I need around 8-10 icons and for the same I do not want to include 100s of KBs of CSS Icon library like Fontawesome (which is really awesome) etc.

**Question:**
Is it possible that I can use a small css and put those 8-10 tags in it? Something like (say myicon.css) this:

myicon.css

```
<svg foo ></svg>
.....
<svg bar ></svg>
```

So that I can include that "small" css in my htmls wherever I need.

If yes how? Any relevant info/hint/solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it is an `svg`, why don't you add them directly in yout html file?

Comment: I dont want to repeat those tags as I have lots of htmls and wish to keep them as clean and readable as possible.